# _argtypes_ must be a sequence of types при работе с dll

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

Подключенная dll имеет 2 параметра, первый это путь к файлу, а второй это запись со следующей структурой:

```
class OType(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("H", ctypes.c_int), 
                ("M", ctypes.c_byte), 
                ("T", ctypes.c_byte)]
```

Но когда пытаюсь задать аргументы структуры

```
funcLF.restype = ctypes.c_int
funcLF.argtypes = ctypes.POINTER(OType)
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PyCharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1477, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\PyCharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/PRIME_NIPI_1210/app_24_project/dllkerneltest.py", line 21, in <module>
    funcLF.argtypes = ctypes.POINTER(OType)
TypeError: _argtypes_ must be a sequence of types
```

Comment: Т.к. аргументов может быть несколько, то argtypes должно быть списком или другим sequence типом (типом поддерживающим итерацию и обращение по индексу, например tuple). Т.е. должно быть так: `funcLF.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(OType)]`

Comment: insolor, спасибо!